# tengo un problema al incluir librería de javascript en Angular

Tags: angular, script

Quiero usar la librerìa typer.js en mi proyecto de Angular pero no he podido hacerla funcionar. Lo que he hecho es crear una carpeta en node_modules con el nombre typer dentro de ella guarde el archivo typer.js, posteriormente modifique el archivo angular.json para agregar la ruta del script pero cuando intento hacer uso en alguna componente no sucede nada. He investigado y esta es la forma como recomiendan agregar alguna librería externa en angular pero no se por que no me funciona. Esta es la librería que quiero agregar: [typer.js](https://steven.codes/typerjs/docs/index.html) y a continuación dejo una captura de los archivos modificados.

angular.json modificado con la ruta del script: [image: angular.json modificado]

agregue también el script en las dependencias en el archivo package.json: [image: también modifique el package.json pero no funciono]

aquí esta el ejemplo tratando de hacer uso de la Liberia: [image: ejemplo de uso en el html]

Gracias de antemano a todo el que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Porque no lo pones en el index tal cual?

Comment: Acabo de probar añadiendo en la cabecera del index la ruta del script y tampoco, no entiendo por que.

Comment: Añade los cómo rutas estáticas en los assets. No recuerdo la configuración. Mañana que esté en mi PC te doy más datos si no encuentras la solución.

Comment: No entiendo lo que tratas de decirme amigo. Si tienes acceso mañana a una pc te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma puede ser agregar tu libreria a la carpeta de assets e importarla en el index.html

```
<script src="./assets/typer.js"></script>
```

Y una para usarla en alguno de tus componenetes podria ser declaradondala afuera de la clase de tu componente.

```
declare var typer: any;
```

Pero en la carpeta **node_module** no tienes nada que hacer, ahi se modifica solo por comandos con **npm** o en relación a lo que tienes declarado en tu **package.json**